Protected Mode Not Enabled
I am developing a custom bootloader for my 64-bit OS in x86_64 NASM on macOS aarch64 (yup, LLDB is only available to me) environment using QEMU. The bootloader is a 2-stage.
Current Behavior

Prints 'Jumped to stage 2'
Enable A20 (which seems to be right)
The bootloader is frozen after A20 and/or between loading kernel to KERNEL_OFFSET_LOW which equals 0x100000

Relevant Code
;
; By alpluspluss 09/22/2024 AD
;
; second stage bootloader
; for x86_64

[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7E00]

section .rodata
KERNEL_OFFSET_HIGH equ 0xFFFF_FFFF_8000_0000
KERNEL_OFFSET_LOW equ 0x100000

section .text
start:
    ; set up segments & stack at 0x9000
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x9000

    ; print 'Jumped to stage 2'
    mov si, stage2Message
    call print_16bit

    mov dl, [bootDrive]

    call enable_A20                 ; enable A20 for mem access beyond 1 MB
    call load_kernel                ; load the rest of stage 2 and kernel
    call enable_protected_mode      ; load GDT and switch to protected mode

; @NOTE: this part is basically 'load_loop' from stage 1
; but has some extras & some stuff removed
load_kernel:
    mov ah, 0x02            ; BIOS read sector function
    mov al, 6               ; read 6 sectors / time
    mov ch, 0               ; cylinder number
    mov cl, 5               ; start from sector 5
    mov dh, 0               ; Head number
    mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET_LOW
    int 0x13                ; read disk op
    jc disk_error           ; jump if disk error
    ret

enable_A20:
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al
    ret

enable_protected_mode:
    cli                             ; disable interrupt
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]           ; load GDT descriptor

    ; init protected mode
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1                       ; set PE bit
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp 0x08:protected_mode_entry   ; jump to segment 0x08

[BITS 32]
protected_mode_entry:
    ; setup segments
    mov ax, 0x10                    ; segment selector
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax

    ; set up stack at 0x200000
    mov esp, 0x200000

    ; say 'Entered protected mode'
    mov esi, protectedModeMessage
    call print_protected_mode

    ; setup paging for long mode
    call setup_paging

    lgdt [gdt64_descriptor]         ; load GDT descriptor in 64-bit

    call enable_long_mode
    jmp 0x08:long_mode_entry        ; jump to segment 0x08 at offset long_mode_entry

setup_paging:
    mov edi, 0x1000                 ; assuming they are 4KB aligned
    xor eax, eax
    mov ecx, 5 * 4096 / 4           ; number of 4 KB entries
    rep stosd                       ; zero page dir and tables

    ; *IMPORTANT*
    ; @NOTE: page fault can happen here
    ; Identity map first 2MB
    ; Map 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000001fffff
    ; to physical 0x00000000-0x001fffff
    mov dword [0x1000], 0x00002003  ; PML4[0] = 0x2000 | PRESENT | READWRITE
    mov dword [0x2000], 0x00003003  ; PDP[0]  = 0x3000 | PRESENT | READWRITE
    mov dword [0x3000], 0x00000083  ; PD[0]   = 0x0000 | PRESENT | READWRITE | 2MB_PAGE

    ; Map 0xFFFFFFFF80000000-0xffffffff801fffff
    ; to physical 0x00000000-0x001fffff
    mov dword [0x1000 + 8 * ((KERNEL_OFFSET_HIGH >> 39) & 0x1ff)], 0x00004003    ; PML4[511] = 0x4000 | PRESENT | READWRITE
    mov dword [0x4000 + 8 * ((KERNEL_OFFSET_HIGH >> 30) & 0x1ff)], 0x00005003    ; PDP[510]  = 0x5000 | PRESENT | READWRITE
    mov dword [0x5000 + 8 * ((KERNEL_OFFSET_HIGH >> 21) & 0x1ff)], 0x00000083    ; PD[0]     = 0x0000 | PRESENT | READWRITE | 2MB_PAGE

    mov edi, 0x1000
    mov cr3, edi                    ; load page dir base into cr3 to set PDBR
    ret

enable_long_mode:
    mov ecx, 0xC0000080
    rdmsr
    or eax, 1 << 8
    wrmsr

    mov eax, 10100000b
    mov cr4, eax

    ; enable PAE and PGE bits in CR0
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1 << 32                 ; enable paging
    mov cr0, eax
    ret

[BITS 64]
long_mode_entry:
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax

    ; setup stack for kernel higher half
    mov rsp, 0x90000 + KERNEL_OFFSET_HIGH

    ; print 'Reached long mode'
    mov rsi, longModeMessage
    call print_long_mode

    mov rax, KERNEL_OFFSET_HIGH + KERNEL_OFFSET_LOW
    jmp rax

[BITS 16]
print_16bit:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done
    mov ah, 0x0E
    int 0x10
    jmp print_16bit
.done:
    ret

[BITS 32]
print_protected_mode:
    push eax
    push ebx
    mov ebx, 0xB8000                ; VGA mem address
.loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done
    mov ah, 0x0F
    mov [ebx], ax
    add ebx, 2
    jmp .loop
.done:
    pop ebx
    pop eax
    ret

[BITS 64]
print_long_mode:
    push rax
    push rbx
    mov rbx, 0xB8000                ; VGA mem address
.loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done
    mov ah, 0x0F
    mov [rbx], ax
    add rbx, 2
    jmp .loop
.done:
    pop rbx
    pop rax
    ret

[BITS 16]
disk_error:
    mov si, diskErrorMessage
    call print_16bit
    cli
    hlt

section .data

bootDrive db 0
stage2Message db 'Jumped to stage 2', 13, 10, 0
diskErrorMessage db 'Disk error in stage 2', 13, 10, 0
longModeMessage db 'Entered long mode', 0
protectedModeMessage db 'Entered protected mode', 0

section .rodata
align 16
gdt_start:
    dq 0x0000000000000000           ; null descriptor
    dq 0x00CF9A000000FFFF           ; 32-bit code descriptor
    dq 0x00CF92000000FFFF           ; 32-bit data descriptor
gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

gdt64_start:
    dq 0x0000000000000000           ; null descriptor
    dq 0x00AF9A000000FFFF           ; 64-bit code descriptor
    dq 0x00AF92000000FFFF           ; 64-bit data descriptor
gdt64_end:

gdt64_descriptor:
    dw gdt64_end - gdt64_start - 1
    dq gdt64_start

section .bss
align 16
stack_bottom:
    resb 16384
stack_top:

section .text
times 512 * 3 - ($ - $$) db 0       ; pad to 3 sectors

After debugging, it seems that enabled mode is not working due to:

Kernel not loading [Likely]
Invalid GDT Descriptor

You can visit the GitHub repository for more details & source code.

Can LLDB connect to QEMU as a GDB-remote like GDB can?  If not you should be able to install GDB. That gives you single-step debugging so you could see if memory contents change after attempting to load a sector.  Or Bochs with its built-in debugger is very good for bootloaders and the switch to protected or long mode since it always knows what the current mode is for disassembling, and can pretty-print GDT and page-table entries to make sure they hold what you intended.  If your current debugging methods can't be sure whether your kernel is loading, use better tools!

mov bx, KERNEL_OFFSET_LOW, where KERNEL_OFFSET_LOW equ 0x100000 which doesn't fit in 16 bits, doesn't look so good.  The 16-bit BIOS can only load into the low 1MB anyway, and you don't have access to anything beyond that until after you are in protected mode.

Nate is correct but on top of that your loop to load sectors in the first stage makes little sense. You tell it to read 2 sectors at a time and then increment by 512. Your stack 0x9c00 is going to get clobbered when reading sectors and causing things to crash. Change it from 0x9c00 to 0x7c00 (below the bootloader where it won't be clobbered by the reads. Then once you do that I am unsure why you are reading the kernel again in the second stage? Doesn't the first stage really just want to read 3 sectors total (the second stage maximum)?

Some of the problems I spoke about in the last question you posted are still a problem here. For instance the Bootdrive variable in the second stage is not the same as the first stage. A lot of these things I pointed out in the comments and fixed in the pastebins I directed you to.

I recommend getting rid of all the section directives in your first stage (by default everything will go in one section. The computation for the disk signature location is incorrect because of the sections. Same with second stage (except for BSS which is okay).

You enable paging with or eax, 1<<32 (which NASM gives a warning about). It should be  or eax, 1<<31

Basically the way I see your code your first stage should only read 3 sectors for the Second stage starting at sector 2. Then your second stage should start at sector 5 and read the kernel (that I can understand using a disk loop for although you will encounter problems since you can't just increase CL indefinitely). Your code should properly handle cylinder/heads/sectors or use extend disk reads to use LBA (but then you wouldn't be able to boot from floppy).

Building  a bootloader might be out of your current level of knowledge. Have you considered using GRUB/multiboot or something else?

As well your linker.ld should be using KERNEL_OFFSET_LOW = 0x10000; and not KERNEL_OFFSET_LOW = 0x100000;

I have placed an amended first_stage.asm (that reads 3 sectors of the second stage at 0x7e00) and the second_stage reads sectors of the kernel (if you want to loop through reads you can modify it do so - I have set it to read 9 sectors and as your kernel grows that would have to be increased). First stage here: https://pastebin.com/2XQYkwU2 . Second stage here: https://pastebin.com/cAgvaF2r and you will have to fix linker.ld as mentioned above.

Note: I don't know what you wanted to do with stack_top and stack_bottom since they aren't currently used in the code. I kept them in there anyway.

In addendum to Nate's comment - you can't using int 0x13 to read to memory above 1MiB (like 0x100000). Int 0x13 is restricted to areas below 1MiB. If you want to load your kernel at 1MiB and above you have to read it to memory below 1MiB and copy it above 1MiB (doing it in chunks). You can of course invest time in using ATA PIO to read from disk but I think that is currently beyond the scope of this question.

At this point in time I'd recommend using BOCHS. I know homebrew among others have a port to Macs. It is ideal for debugging real mode bootloaders and the transitions between modes (like real mode protected mode, long mode etc).

@MichaelPetch Looking back here, the bootloader is up running perfectly. Your help on the code really helped me set up the kernel running :). One last thing, could you please post the solution so I could mark this question as solved?

You may self answer this question, please be my guest.
